# Is there a way to generate function names with iterated number using macros/templates in c/c++?

Tags: c++, templates, macros

I have the following code

```
extern "C" void interrupt_handler_0();
extern "C" void interrupt_handler_1();
extern "C" void interrupt_handler_2();
...

void func() {
  setup_isr(0, interrupt_handler_0);
  setup_isr(1, interrupt_handler_1);
  setup_isr(2, interrupt_handler_2);
  ...
}
```

in the example I only have 3 of each of these lines but in reality there are a lot more, I was trying to get rid of all these repeated lines somehow.

My original idea was to do some kind of macro to generate these without me having to have them all written down.
Something along the lines of `#define ISR_NAME(number) interrupt_handler_##number()` and then just have a loop that iterates number.
After much googling and a few attempts, I am starting to think this is not actually possible? Sure you can make a macro loop but the iterated value i doesn't actually get computed in preprocessor time. So I'll always end up with something like `interrupt_handler_0+1+1+1+1();`.

Is this right or am I missing something? Is there some other way that I am missing to make this work?

I am still rather new to c++ so I don't know much about templates except they are a way to do meta-programming in c++. I am actually not sure if they are applicable to this problem but since this piece of code is actually from a c++ project solutions using c++/templates instead of macros are also accepted.

Comment: Use a script to generate the source code.

Comment: Do not tag both C and C++ except when asking about differences or interactions between the two languages.

Comment: Use [BOOST_PP_REPEAT](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/repeat.html).

Comment: Do the functions have identical body? If yes, why do you need multiple functions instead of assigning 1 function as handler multiple times?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen no they have different bodies.

Comment: In the embedded systems world, the usual method is to have one ISR that obtains the interrupt number then delegates functionality (e.g. `switch`), based on the interrupt number.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I mean that might solve my problem in a somewhat roundabout way but part of the reason I did it this way was that as far as I am aware interrupt handlers in x86 aren't called with parameters, so if I associated the generic interrupt handler to all the interrupts once the interrupt handler was called I would have no way to know which interrupt was triggered. In practice all these interrupt_handler_x are wrappers that call a generic interrupt handler with the interrupt number and the error code(when applicable) as parameters.

Comment: Can you make an array of function pointers and iterate over/index into that array?

Comment: @Ben Sure, I've thought of that but the whole point of this was to not have an explicitly written endless stream of functions, for reasons of code aesthetics and maintainability(and yes I'm aware these are somewhat subjective) but it seems to me that if I have to write that list anyways to initialize that array I'm right where I started, I've just moved the problem.

Comment: It's not clear to me if you are trying to automate the `extern "C"` lines or the `setup_isr` lines. I'm a little dubious of automating the `extern "C"` lines in that I'd rather see the API explicitly listed. I think you want a macro solution to avoid copy-pasting, but I think the copy-paste into an array is reasonable, and lets you index the functions by number at compile time or runtime, and produces the same assembly as your version: https://godbolt.org/z/9znv6zKqY Actually, I think this is what you want: https://godbolt.org/z/xPoPGxGMM